# ERROR message : EXT4-fs error: ext4_find_entry 1535

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

Running Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. Trying to plot Chia (crypto coin on HDDs) but my system keeps crashing with the below message. Brand new 4 terabyte ssd, I've ran fsck and no errors appear.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 3.74 TiB, 4096805658624 bytes, 8001573552 sectors
Disk model: XPG SPECTRIX S40G                       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 478EE428-106D-4005-AADC-C1C6463B4712

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 8001572863 8000522240  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

[screen-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnCAu.jpg)

[screen-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq8xL.jpg)

Comment: Exactly how did you initialize/format/build the new SSD? What brand/model SSD? Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`.

Comment: @heynnema ADATA XPG SPECTRIX S40G RGB 4 TB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive. formatted as ext4, but I was thinking about formatting as xfs to see if that helps. Will do

Comment: Go to the ADATA web site and look for a firmware update for that model #. Did you lay down a fresh GPT Partition Table before creating the ext4 partition? Is this SSD connected to an internal SATA port, or as an external USB3 drive?

Comment: @heynnema I did not lay down a fresh partition table beforehand (I'm a new Linux user with a windows bg). its connected via an M.2M.2 slot, neither SATA nor USB.

Comment: Since the corrected `fdisk` command shows that the disk IS in gpt format, my answer is invalid, and I'll delete it.

Comment: Check for a firmware update for the ADATA SSD.

Comment: Thanks - I can't seem to find any downloadable firmware for that model. I'll email the support then. Would you suggest formatting the SSD with a different file system (NTFS, xfs)?  @heynnema

Comment: No, ext4 should work fine... unless you're planning on sharing files with Windows, then I'd also create a NTFS partition for that.

Comment: Web page is at https://www.xpg.com/us/xpg/610?tab=description

Comment: On the slight chance that the SSD is not properly seated into the M.2 connector, physically REMOVE the SSD, reinstall it, and make sure that it's pushed firmly into its slot, and properly screwed down to the chassis/frame.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the link, but it doesn't seem to have any drivers.

Comment: The Downloads page doesn't show any firmware updates... but that doesn't mean that ADATA doesn't have any. Did you reseat the SSD in its M.2 connector? Do contact their Support and ask about firmware. You may also have a defective SSD.

Comment: Status please...